# jqgrid form editing problem

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with mvc 2 like this:

```
jQuery("#extension_grid").jqGrid({
        url: '/Extension/Report',
        datatype: "json",
        direction: "rtl",
        height: "auto",
        jsonReader: { root: "rows", page: "page", total: "total", records: "records", repeatitems:       false, userdata: "UserData" },
        colModel:
        [
        { name: 'id', label: 'داخلی', key: true, search: true, width: 55 },
        { name: 'assigned_user', label: 'کاربر', width: 90, editable: true },
        { name: 'creation_date', label: 'تاریخ ایجاد', width: 100, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'} }
        ],
        rowNum: -1,
        pager: '#extension_pager',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "داخلی‌ها",
        editurl: '/Extension/MyEdit'
    });
    jQuery("#extension_grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#extension_pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });
```

when I select a row and click the edit button a dialog appears and I can edit the row. after submit, data is posted to the editurl successfully. but changes are not saved to grid client side. should I save the changes client side manually? 
I tried with datatype local and it works!!! what should I do? is there any problem with using json data and form editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation which you described seems me very strange. There are default setting `reloadAfterSubmit:true` for "Add" and "Edit" forms. It means that after submitting of the "Edit" form for example the grid contain will be reloaded. You can verify with respect of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) that the grid reloading take place. So either your server part '/Extension/MyEdit' not save the data or another the server '/Extension/Report' don't get the refreshed data. Do you have some kind of data caching on the server?

So you should analyse the problem which you have more exctly. If you would not solve the problem yourself you should update/append your question with more additional information.

Comment: thanx for your answer. The problem was the way I was thinking jqGrid works. I thought that jqgrid applies changes locally (client side) after sending edit data to server and receiving success. but really changes are populated after data is reloaded from server. I was testing and I wasn't reflecting data to data base.

Comment: @user590747: Could you seen that the server send back **old data**? Why your server applikation do this? By the way you can set `reloadAfterSubmit:false` in the "Edit" options of `navGrid` (see `prmEdit` parameter [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition)). In the case the jqGrid will update the grid data after successful submiting to `'/Extension/MyEdit'`